# The group acts on an ordered set

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group, $G$ acts on an ordered set and preserves its order, i.e. $a<b$, then $g(a)<g(b)$ for $g\in G$. Then does it imply there is a left order on $G$, i.e. $f<g$, then $fh<gh$ for $h\in G$?

Comment: Can you write your question more clear, please ? Do you mean that $g(a)<g(b)$ for all $g\in G$ ? and if so, In second case, Do you mean that there is an order in $G$ which respect group multiplication ? And do you mean strict order ?

Answer (score 1):

No. Form a diamond with $M$ the unique maximum, $m$ the unique minimum, and $x,y$ two incomparable elements that are both in between $M$ and $m$. We can let $G=C_2$ act by switching $x$ and $y$ and leaving the max/min fixed. This preserves the ordering, but there is no possible ordering on $G$ compatible with the group operation.